# Requirements Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu

I have a HP Compaq Tc4400 with 2,5gb RAM with Intel Core Duo T5600 / 1.83 GHz.

My question is, what version can I install 32 bits or 64? I tried the x64 one but its a little bit laggy.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-tc4400/specs/

The CPU is T2500. And according to Intel:

http://ark.intel.com/products/27236/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2500-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-667-MHz-FSB

The CPU supports a 32 bit instruction set. So you'll want the 32 bit version. Installing the 32 bit version should sort you out.

To download the 32 bit version go here:

http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

Click on the version you want and it should expand. Then you can click to download the 32 bit ISO.

Comment: That page is not correct. The specs are the are the ones I've put. I installed Windows 10 in x64 architecture and it works perfectly because is a 64 processor. I will give a try to the x64 version and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Every site that I've checked indicates that is the name of the CPU and, according to Intel (the makers of the CPU) the instruction set is limited to 32 bits. Give the 32 bit version a try and let us know if it does the trick.